# My VPS running on Ubuntu using Nginx Crashed and wont run again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu, nginx

I'm new to setting up VPS.

Earlier tonight I set up an VPS using Ubuntu, Postgresql, Nginx, Passenger.

It went very well until the APP broke, and now I always get the `Sorry, something went wrong` msg when I refresh the page.

I've restarted NginX using `sudo service nginx restart`
And I've restarted the `postgresql` also.

I've also `deployed`the app again and again with out no luck.

In the `production.log`

there are this messages:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:101:in `each'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:101:in `reduce'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:101:in `users_stats'
```

Now this error is always coming up. Even after all the restarts.

**UPDATE**

here is the code, I managed to make it work by commenting it out of the controller and deploy again.

```
all_users_truck_use = User.joins(:transports).where(transports: { transport_type: ['Truck / Lorry', nil] } ).pluck(:transport_km).reduce(:+)
 @all_users_Truck_co2 = all_users_truck_use.nil? ? 0 : all_users_truck_use * @Truck.to_f
```

Is the server ins some kind of a loop or?
I'm really getting desperate here, I need to deliver this project on Monday morning.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please show us your `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` file especially - the code around line `101`. Hint the code in line 101 raises an error because it tries to call add (`+`) on something that is `nil`.

Comment: pleas see my update @spickermann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `NoMethodError (undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass)` tells you that you try to call `+` on `nil`. That error happens if you do something like `nil + 1` whereas `1 + nil` would raise a different error.

And I assume that the following line (reformated for readability) is line `101` in your `application_controller.rb`

```
all_users_truck_use = User
  .joins(:transports)
  .where(transports: { transport_type: ['Truck / Lorry', nil] } )
  .pluck(:transport_km)
  .reduce(:+)
```

From the docs of `reduce`:

> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

That means the first element returned of `User.joins(:transports).where(transports: { transport_type: ['Truck / Lorry', nil] } ).pluck(:transport_km)` must be `nil`.

A very simple solution might be to remove `nil` values from that list by calling `compact` before `reduce`:

```
all_users_truck_use = User
  .joins(:transports)
  .where(transports: { transport_type: ['Truck / Lorry', nil] } )
  .pluck(:transport_km)
  .compact
  .reduce(:+)
```

Better solutions might be to add a validation to ensure that all database records have a valid `transport_km` and clean up existing records. Or to do the calculation completely in `SQL`. Hard to tell without more information how your database schema loads like, where the data is coming from and how the context of this line and its use case looks like.